# How do I add a column based on selected row filter in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I would like to give a final score to the students based on current Score + Score for their favourite subject.

```
import pandas as pd
new_data = [['tom', 31, 50, 30, 20, 'English'], ['nick', 30, 42, 23, 21, 'Math'], ['juli', 39, 14, 40, 38, 'Science']]
df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns = ['Name','Current_Score','English','Science','Math','Favourite_Subject'])
for subj in df['Favourite_Subject'].unique():
    mask = (df['Favourite_Subject'] == subj)
    df['Final_Score'] = df[mask].apply(lambda row: row['Current_Score'] + row[subj], axis=1)

    Name    Score   English Science Math    Favourite_Subject   Final_Score
0   tom       31       50    30      20         English          NaN
1   nick      30       42    23      21         Math             NaN
2   juli      39       14    40      38         Science          79.0
```

When I apply the above function, I got NaN in the other 2 entries for 'Final_Score' column, how do I get the following result without overwriting with NaN? Thanks!

```
    Name    Score   English Science Math    Favourite_Subject   Final_Score
0   tom       31       50    30      20         English          81
1   nick      30       42    23      21         Math             51
2   juli      39       14    40      38         Science          79
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `lookup` to find the scores corresponding to the `Favourite_Subject` then add them with the `Current_Score` to calculate `Final_Score`

```
i = df.columns.get_indexer(df['Favourite_Subject'])
df['Final_Score'] = df['Current_Score'] + df.values[df.index, i]
```

---

```
   Name  Current_Score  English  Science  Math Favourite_Subject Final_Score
0   tom             31       50       30    20           English          81
1  nick             30       42       23    21              Math          51
2  juli             39       14       40    38           Science          79
```

Comment: *Warning: `Index.get_indexer` will return -1 if the value in the column is not found in the column headers. Because python supports relative slicing, selecting the -1 index will return a value from the last column column in the DataFrame (in this case "Favourite_Subject"). The docs recommend `factorize` which will return NaN if there are missing values. [An answer with both options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68976400/15497888), [the official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup)

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes `factorize` is a proper way to do the lookup. Its good to know that the pandas team have added that in the official docs. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Any time :) `get_indexer` works in most cases (and it's I think a bit more legible in terms of what it's doing), but it can be confusing that the not found indicator is "-1" given how it is typically used.

Comment: @HenryEcker I totally agree with you. Feel free to edit the answer if you like :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a loop, you can apply this directly to the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
new_data = [['tom', 31, 50, 30, 20, 'English'], ['nick', 30, 42, 23, 21, 'Math'], ['juli', 39, 14, 40, 38, 'Science']]
df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns = ['Name','Current_Score','English','Science','Math','Favourite_Subject'])
df['Final_Score'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Current_Score'] + x[x['Favourite_Subject']], axis=1)
```

Comment: ``apply`` is a loop

Comment: @sammywemmy technically yeah, but what I mean is that it is more efficient than using the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on `axis=1` and get the column label from the column value of column `Favourite_Subject` to get the value of the corresponding column.  Then, add the result to column `Current_Score` with `df['Current_Score']`, as follows:

```
df['Final_Score'] = df['Current_Score'] + df.apply(lambda x: x[x['Favourite_Subject']], axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   Name  Current_Score  English  Science  Math Favourite_Subject  Final_Score
0   tom             31       50       30    20           English           81
1  nick             30       42       23    21              Math           51
2  juli             39       14       40    38           Science           79
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are overwriting the previous values during each loop which is why you only have the Final score for the final row when the loop ends.

Here is my implementation:

```
import pandas as pd
new_data = [['tom', 31, 50, 30, 20, 'English'], ['nick', 30, 42, 23, 21, 'Math'], ['juli', 39, 14, 40, 38, 'Science']]
df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns = ['Name','Current_Score','English','Science','Math','Favourite_Subject'])

favsubj = df['Favourite_Subject'].to_list()
final_scores = []
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    final_scores.append(df['Current_Score'].iloc[i] + df[favsubj[i]].iloc[i])

df['Final_Score'] = final_scores
```